# How to get the content of the current node

Tags: c#, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I have a html source like below

```
 <div class="home">
    <table class="player" style="top:xx;left:yy"><tbody>...</tbody</table>
    <table class="player" style="top:xx;left:yy"><tbody>...</tbody</table>
    <table class="player" style="top:xx;left:yy"><tbody>...</tbody</table>
    <table class="player" style="top:xx;left:yy"><tbody>...</tbody</table>
 </div>
```

Getting players:

```
var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
var ele = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.ClassName("home")));
var players = ele.FindElements(By.ClassName("player"));
```

Is there any efficient way to get the whole table content

```
  foreach (var player in players)
  {
      var html = player.GetAttribute("innerHTML");  >> only get <tbody> stuff 
  }
```

Comment: What do you mean by getting *whole table content*? Can you provide expected result

Comment: You should take a look at the Html Agility Pack.  It's a very useful toolkit for parsing html and getting what you want in an efficient manner.

Comment: @sergey:  <table><tbody>...</tbody></table> not just the tbody tag

Comment: @steve they're all xpath stuff, htmlagilitypack will return tbody as well. any suggestion on xpath query ?

Comment: xpath something like '//table/node()'.  I'm not excessively familiar with it, but it should be something like that

Comment: If you use HtmlAgilityPack, it has `OuterHtml` property which return whole table, also `InnerHtml` property which return only tbody...